# C# ScrollView - scroll is always disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a rather simple thing, which should load a .jpg file, put it inside scroll viewer so I can scroll to see the whole picture. But from some reason ScrollViewer never activates the scrolls, but the picture is too big and is not showed completely.
It loads a .jpg this way:

```
Image image = new Image{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[0]))
    };
mainPanel.Children.Add(image);
```

What I have in .xaml is:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas x:Name="mainPanel"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Canvas` control and put `Image` directly as `ScrollViewer.Content`

```
<ScrollViewer 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image x:Name="myImage"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and in code

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[0]));
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Canvas has default Height and Width properties of zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes its child elements.